# JSON items data types python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, flatten

I have the following JSON structure.

[image]

Goal is to identify datatypes of each nested keys under `items` hierarchy.

```
for i, item in enumerate(data['_embedded']['items']):
 for key, values in item.items():
        if isinstance(values, dict):
            print(values, ' is dict')
        elif isinstance(values, list):
            print(values, ' is list')
        elif isinstance(values, str):
            print(values, ' is str')
```

output is:

```
{'self':PCR-0006894-SAMKG0-PC'}}  is dict
    PCR-0006894-SAMKG0-PC  is str
    products  is str
etc.
```

so it just gives me the value types in each key, but desired output based on the above attached JSON structure should be

```
_links is dict
identifier is str
enabled is bool
family is str
categories is list
```

when i change `if isinstance(values, dict):` to `if isinstance(key, dict):` it prints that everything is str but it is not true

Comment: Why are you printing the value when you want the key?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you meant to have: `print(key, ' is dict')` etc.

Comment: well, I also mentioned in the end of my question that when i put `key` it just print that every key is `str` which is not true if you look at the image of JSON structure i attchaed

Comment: Not it isn't. At the end of your question you added that you'd tried: `if isinstance(key, dict):`. This will result in only `if isinstance(key, str):` being true since the source is `json` where *every* key *has* to be a string.

Comment: well how can I identify if the key has values stored as `dict`, `str` or `list`? this is my goal, that I tried with above code

Comment: Well, did you try: `print(key, ' is dict')` etc?

Comment: sorry I dont get it

Comment: okay I got it now and I achived it what I wanted with this `            if isinstance(values, dict):
                print(key,'dict')`